# Oracle wait for table update in procedure

Tags: oracle, asynchronous, plsql

I've two databases (for example let's call them A and B) with one-way dblink - security restriction on one base (A) doesn't allow to connect from outside.

I need to put some data from B to A, process it and return a response. This task was done in this way:

1. On database B I made 2 tables - REQUESTS_IN (req_id number, data clob) and REQUESTS_OUT (req_id number, data clob). When I need to send data to db A I put it into REQUESTS_IN and start job which is checking any new rows in REQUESTS_OUT.
2. On database A there is a job which checks for new rows in REQUESTS_IN using dblink, gets data, processes it and put answer into REQUESTS_OUT.

Based on data process business logic, jobs delay - it can take up to 1 minute to get response in REQUESTS_OUT. It's ok when application is async and can wait for response.

Now i need to make sync version of this solution. On database B application will call some function to send data to database A and it needs to return response in same call.

I tried to find a solution in oracle db functions, but the only thing that comes to mind is to use dbms_pipe. i.e. on database B use dbms_pipe.receive_message to wait for message and on database A use dbms_pipe.send_message. But i'm not sure if this is correct solution.

Comment: *The [DBMS_PIPE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_PIPE.html#GUID-84B9B55F-9D82-45D0-B9CA-9A6AEEF9C8F8) package lets two or more sessions **in the same instance** communicate*. You can turn any async processing to sync by waiting for the responce with the same session identifier (whatever used for this purpose) in outbound queue (by checking the table with `dbms_lock.sleep` between calls). But you'll need to setup appropriate timeout and error handling.

Comment: So, i can't use dbms_pipe over dblink? It won't count as 2 sessions in same instance? I was thinking about dbms_lock.sleep (to use in loop with checking table), but i thought there might be other solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that. Of course it will be a different session at the same instance, so looks like a possible solution

Comment: Check out DBMS_AQ. Put a request on a queue with correlation ID, and then let the responder put the response back with that same ID and the calling session can wait for it